# Schedule Messaging.sendEmail()

Tags: apex, trigger, email, scheduled-apex

I'm looking for a way, through Apex to Schedule sending `SingleEmailMessages` using `Messaging.sendEmail();`.

I've got a Trigger that sends e-mail straight away once the method is invoked that looks like below:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
email.setTemplateId(templateId);
email.setTargetObjectId(application.ts2__Candidate_Contact__c);

mailList.add(email);
```

However before I call the `Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);` method, I'm checking to see what time it is. Specifically, if it's between 9am and 9pm, we can instantly send the e-mail. Otherwise we want to schedule sending it as below:

```
Integer hour = System.now().hour();

if (hour > 9 && hour < 21) {
  Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
}
else {
  // Schedule the e-mail
}
```

Now I've tried a few things and feel like I'm on the right track, but I think I'm going about it the wrong way. For instance, within the `else` statement:

```
String day = System.now().addDays(1).format('dd');
String month = System.now().addDays(1).format('MM');
String year = System.now().addDays(1).format('yyyy');

String CRON_EXP = '0 0 9 ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' + year + '';
System.schedule('Schedule_Send_Email', CRON_EXP, new Messaging.sendEmail(mailList));
```

This fails expecting something totally different.

I've also tried using `System.schedule` on a class that implements Schedulable which inevitably failed (clutching at straws I think!) and even considered a Batch class although this seems totally wrong and I'm not entirely sure what the syntax of that would be.

Simple question: **How can I schedule/delay sending an e-mail until a given time?**

If you were wondering, Time-Based Workflows can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still must implement `Schedulable`. Unfortunately, the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` type is not serializable, so you'll need to store a wrapper instead. Something like:

```
public class DeferredEmail implements Schedulable
{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext  context)
    {
        Messaging.sendEmail(generateEmails());
    }

    final List<MessagePacket> messages;
    public DeferredEmail()
    {
        messages = new List<MessagePacket>{new MessagePacket()};
    }
    public List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> generateEmails()
    {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (MessagePacket message : messages) emails.add(message.generateEmail());
        return emails;
    }
    public DeferredEmail add(String toAddress, Id templateId, Id targetObjectId)
    {
        messages.add(new MessagePacket(toAddress, templateId, targetObjectId));
        return this;
    }

    public class MessagePacket
    {
        public final Id templateId;
        public final Id targetObjectId;
        public final String toAddress;
        public Messaging.SingleEmailMessage generateEmail()
        {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToAddresses(new List<String> { toAddress });
            email.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId);
            email.setTemplateId(templateId);
            return email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've tried creating a separate Schedule class (I'll add it to the question) but I'm getting the error: `System.UnexpectedException: Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Messaging/SingleEmailMessage$$r ()`. Do you know what this means? Not come across it before.

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks Adrian. Salesforce is taking at least 10 minutes to compile today. As soon as it wakes up I'll let you know!

Comment: Works like a charm. Sorry it took so long to get back to you, watching the equals sign bounce around in Sublime for 30 minutes is more excruciating than it should be.

Comment: @Poet No problem! When it's really bad I just switch to developer console. Are you using `Metadata API` or `Tooling API`? I've heard there are serious compile issues using the `Metadata API` these days. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136379/anyone-else-having-issues-with-deployment-to-sandbox-stuck-in-pending-for-5-60-m

Comment: I'm actually using the Tooling API as it happens although slow compiling pretty intermittent to be fair, sometimes I wonder if it's our Org. Regardless, it doesn't seem to be a whole lot better than what the Metadata API right now! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AdrianLarson Hello Adrian! I believe that it's only one solution in the internet for that problem))) could you please to write an example, how to create custom emails with this wrapper? THANK YOU!