# Null pointer Exception on apex batch Salesforce

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, apex-email-service

```
global class NotifyBatch2 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful {

/public string query = 'select Id, name,Status__c,CreatedDate  from MR_Product__c where Status__c= \'Pending Submission\' And CreatedDate=System.today()-CreatedDate>24';
datetime dt = System.now()-1;
public string query = 'select Id, name,Status__c,CreatedDate,Materials_Meeting_Date__c,Materials_Due_Date__c,CreatedBy.Email,Submitter__c,Book_Coverage__c,Notes__c,Materials_Request_Organization__c from MR_Product__c where Status__c=\'Pending Submission\'';
//And CreatedDate >:dt';


public transient List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>  mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();



global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
  System.debug('CheckRecords:' + query);

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, Sobject[] scope)
{ 



    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Id, Body  from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'BOOK_REQUEST_Template'];

    for (MR_Product__c  item : (List<MR_Product__c>)scope) {


            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
             string MatDueDate = string.valueOfGmt(item.Materials_Due_Date__c);
             string MatMeetingDate = string.valueOfGmt(item.Materials_Meeting_Date__c);      

                    string body = emailTemplate.body;

                    body  = body.replace('{!MR_Product__c.Submitter__c}', item.Submitter__c);
                    body  = body.replace('{!MR_Product__c.Materials_Request_Organization__c}', item.Materials_Request_Organization__c);
                    body  = body.replace('{!MR_Product__c.Materials_Due_Date__c}', MatDueDate );
                    body  = body.replace('{!MR_Product__c.Materials_Meeting_Date__c}', MatMeetingDate);

                    if(item.Notes__c!=null && item.Notes__c!=''){
                    body  = body.replace('{!MR_Product__c.Notes__c}', item.Notes__c);
                    }
                     if(item.Book_Coverage__c!=null && item.Book_Coverage__c!=''){
                    body  = body.replace('{!MR_Product__c.Book_Coverage__c}', item.Book_Coverage__c);

                    }

                    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {item.createdby.Email});
                    email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    email.setPlainTextBody(body);
                    //email.setTargetObjectId(item.id);
                    email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
                    //email.setWhatId(item.Id);
                    system.debug('Checkemails' + email);
                    mails.add(email);

          // Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});



    }





}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {


    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);



}




}
```

I'm trying to execute this batch apex class. All I want is to do is send emails in the finish method but whenever I declare the list (mails) at global level a null pointer exception is thrown. Find the error message below:

> Class.MaterialRequestNotifyBatch2.execute: line 58, column 1

on line number 58 I have the following code: `mails.add(email);`

Comment: Try Removing the transient keyword, that's the only bit that doesn't make sense to me right now.

Comment: If i remove transient keyword its shows : First error: Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Messaging/SingleEmailMessage$$r

Comment: This question displays more or less the same problem as https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/137323/2995

Answer (score 1):

I recollect that email messages are not serializable which may be why `transient` has been added.

So instead create your own class (can be a nested class of `NotifyBatch2`) that has the required attributes to capture the information you want to email and add to a list of those declared as a non-transient class property. Then in the `finish` method convert those objects to `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` objects and send them.

Answer (score 0):

transient variables has a local access. So even if you have declared it globally, it will store null value inside the method `execute`, as it is not initialized there.
For that same reason it will not get null pointer in the `Messaging.sendEmail(mails);` next.

You have one possible way to do this -

Try initialize within `execute` method. Also use the `Messaging.sendEmail(mails);` within this `execute` method.