# Issue: Long pending time when deploying to develop org

Tags: deployment, ant, migration-tool, mavensmate

Related Issue [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136379/anyone-else-having-issues-with-deployment-to-sandbox-stuck-in-pending-for-5-60-m)

Having two develop orgs on NA35. Whenever I deploy using "ant" or "MavensMate" either way the deployment keep pending for long long time. They usually get start after 30+ mins.

I still haven't find a way to solve this. I tried reinstalled "ant" and JDK8. Limited Log. Cleaning all the Scheduled job before. Nothing helps.

Short term solution for me right now is using developer console to save all classes.

Comment: No issues in trust.salesforce.com for today for NA35. Check https://status.salesforce.com/status/NA35

Comment: @SLman Thanks for point this out. I constantly checking those servers status. I have another org on NA30 which is totally fine. This pending issue also happen to my team member today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, this is a Known Issue with no scheduled resolution date:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000enp0QAA

For posterity:

> Summary: Intermittent slowness observed on NA35 during deployments
>
> Repro: The current architecture uses a queuing framework for all
>   deployment requests. This is a reflection of the fact that deployment
>   was built to support packaging, change sets, and the ant tool -
>   release management use cases that are typically larger deployments.
>
> Dev Tooling (IDE) use cases have been supported by this same
>   framework. And, although we have run into some similar issues in the
>   past, they have not been as consistent as they have been in the past
>   two releases. These smaller deploys have started to suffer due to the
>   increased sophistication of customer's development processes. Simply
>   put, we have seen a lot of continuous integration development. This is
>   a great sign for our platform, except for the fact that we are
>   responding to the extra load we are seeing.
>
> That said, we are working on a few things targeting the smaller
>   deployments. We have finished a costing engine this release and we
>   have added a few new queues. This will allow us to target the smaller
>   deployments and have them on their own queue. The fair usage system
>   which governs our queuing system will only degrade large deployments,
>   which are much fewer than the smaller tooling deployments. This is
>   only in pilot in our Feb release as we need to monitor this before
>   rolling it out everywhere.
>
> So, there are good things coming, but you won't see the results of
>   this work until the spring/summer time frame. In the mean time, please
>   keep the dialogue open and continue to submit the cases, so that we
>   have a good understanding of the overall affect.
>
> Workaround: Also, if you are building CI systems, please separate
>   deployment from testing. When you include tests in the deploy, the
>   overall deployment will take longer which will count against the
>   metadata service when it is evaluated for fair usage on an instance.
>   Execute the deployment without tests, if possible, and then kick off
>   the tests through the Tooling api.

Comment: Got it. Guess I'll just use other non-NA35 org. Thanks!